# Android - Forcing orientation in smartphones only

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation, orientation-changes, android-configchanges

My app has 3 screens, and all of them must be portrait-only in smartphones and both orientation for tablets.

Unitl now I was using the following code in `OnCreate`:

```
if (!getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet)) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

However if I hold the smartphone in landscape mode and launch the application it will show in landscape for a few seconds then rotate to portrait.

Many answers here suggest locking orientation via manifest, but that would lock the orientation in tablets, which is not desired.

I would be very grateful for any information that leads me to a solution. Thanks.

Comment: When are you calling this code? Try doing it *before* the call to `setContentView()` if you're not already.

Comment: It is done in the first line inside the `onCreate`, before `setContentView()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could lock it in the Manifest and then unlock it in code if it's a tablet.

It may not matter for your case, but I've read that the Nexus 7 doesn't report itself as a tablet using the method you do.  I'm not sure that's accurate though, never having tried it myself.

Comment: What exactly would I do to unlock in code? 

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED)`?


Because I think it would create the reverse effect in tablets, they would load as portrait then rotate to landscape.

BTW, for detecting if the device is a tablet I am checking for screen size, large devices and above set a boolean resource `isTablet` to true.

Comment: Oh I thought you were using some built-in boolean that I've heard rumors about.  It may cause the reverse effect in tablets, I can't think of any other way to do it though.  You could have a splash screen when your app starts, figure out the orientation requirements while that's displayed, and then move into the real app once it's figured out.

Comment: One of the screens is the splash screen already, where the issue happens.